# $\sqrt{\text{Nested} \sqrt{\text{root} \sqrt{\text{problem}}}}$

Tags: discussion, mathjax

## Problem

In the PSQ [How to prove $\sqrt{6+2\sqrt{7+3\sqrt{8+\cdots}}}=4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4012541/290189), I observe that the vertical separations above and below the middle square root sign are uneven.

```
\sqrt{6+2\sqrt{7+3\sqrt{8+\cdots}}}
```

[image: error screenshot]
Screenshot taken using Firefox 84.0.2 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 20.04

Is there a way to make the two vertical separations look even?

## Effort

It seems fine in `\displaystyle` when it's rendered from editor preview.

$$\sqrt{6+2\sqrt{7+3\sqrt{8+\cdots}}}$$

[image: screenshot including answer]
Screenshot taken using same browser on same OS as above

Comment: As this has floated to the top again, I thought I should say: I dislike question titles which are all MathJax and no text. I tend to open questions by right-clicking on their titles, and this is not possible with all-MathJax titles.

Comment: @user1729 Thanks for feedback.  Next time, I'd try "I have a $\sqrt{\text{Nested} \sqrt{\text{root} \sqrt{\text{problem}}}}$".

Comment: @user1729 On a related note, main site questions with *any* MathJax in the title are blocked by the HNQ algorithm, which has a very distorting affect on which Math SE questions end up appearing on the HNQ list. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237475/334566 & https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756/334566

Comment: @user1729 Re my answer/response to your comment, even if you already knew this info, perhaps other mathSE reviewers did not.

Comment: @user1729, relatable, I usually right-click on questions and hit Open in New Tab so that I can still browse through more questions while I have the questions I want to look at ready to look at

Comment: I might be going off on a tangent here, but could someone help with writing code to approximate such expressions?

Comment: @F.N. on the main site, we have an approximation tag for questions about approximating a value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another option is to use [`\mathstrut`](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm#mathstrut), eg $\sqrt{ 6+2\sqrt{ 7+3\sqrt{\mathstrut 8+\cdots}}}$, which is produced from `$\sqrt{ 6+2\sqrt{ 7+3\sqrt{\mathstrut 8+\cdots}}}$`.

Comment: Thank you!  That's much better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

One-line solution $\sqrt{\vphantom{\bigcup} 6+2\sqrt{\vphantom{\bigcup} 7+3\sqrt{\vphantom{\bigcup} 8+\cdots}}}$ using `\vphantom{\bigcup}`:
`$\sqrt{\vphantom{\bigcup} 6+2\sqrt{\vphantom{\bigcup} 7+3\sqrt{\vphantom{\bigcup} 8+\cdots}}}$`

Comment: I might be going off on a tangent here, but could you help with writing code to approximate such expressions?

Comment: @F.N. sor9y for my intimely response.  i suggest asking on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

***tl;dr*–**  Using `\mathstrut` or/and `\displaystyle` might help.

---

Comparisons:$$
\begin{array}{rcc}
\textbf{Normal:}
& \sqrt{6 + 2\sqrt{7 + 3\sqrt{8+\cdots}}}
& \left(1\right)
\\
\textbf{With}~\texttt{\mathstrut}\textbf{:}
& \sqrt{6 + 2\sqrt{7 + 3\sqrt{\mathstrut 8 + \cdots}}}
& \left(2\right)
\\
\textbf{With}~\texttt{\displaystyle}\textbf{:}
& {\displaystyle \sqrt{6 + 2 \sqrt{7 + 3\sqrt{8 + \cdots}}}}
& \left(3\right)
\\
\begin{array}{r}\textbf{With}~\texttt{\mathstrut} \\[-25px]\textbf{and}~\texttt{\displaystyle}\end{array}\textbf{:}
& {\displaystyle \sqrt{6 + 2 \sqrt{7 + 3\sqrt{\mathstrut 8 + \cdots}}}}
& \left(4\right)
\end{array}
_{.}
$$

$\mathrm{\TeX} :$

1. **Normal:**
   `\sqrt{6 + 2\sqrt{7 + 3\sqrt{8+\cdots}}}`
2. **With `\mathstrut`:**
   `\sqrt{6 + 2\sqrt{7 + 3\sqrt{\mathstrut 8 + \cdots}}}`
3. **With `\displaystyle`:**
   `\displaystyle \sqrt{6 + 2 \sqrt{7 + 3\sqrt{8 + \cdots}}}`
4. **With `\mathstrut` and `\displaystyle`:**
   `\displaystyle \sqrt{6 + 2 \sqrt{7 + 3\sqrt{\mathstrut 8 + \cdots}}}`

Comment: Just in case anyone else was curious what they looked like side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

***tl;dr*–**  This answer plays with spacing just for fun.

---

[@PM2Ring's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33115/286385) suggested `\mathstrut`, then [@GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33111/286385) tried constructing a similar mechanism through `\vphantom{\bigcup}`.

So, in that spirit and just for fun, trying `\vphantom` with differing heights, mostly just to see what they look like:
$$
{\def\Spacing#1{\vphantom{\rule{0em}{#1em}}}}
{\def\Example#1#2{
{#2{\sqrt{6 + 2 \sqrt{7 + 3\sqrt{\Spacing{#1} 8 + \cdots}}}}}}}
{\def\Row#1{\\ \text{#1} & \Example{#1}{} & \Example{#1}{\displaystyle}}}
\begin{array}{lcc}
\begin{array}{c}\textbf{Height} \\[-25px] \left(\texttt{em}\right)\end{array}
& \begin{array}{c}\textbf{Rendering, without} \\[-25px] \texttt{\displaystyle} \end{array}
& \begin{array}{c}\textbf{Rendering, with} \\[-25px] \texttt{\displaystyle} \end{array}
\Row{0}
\Row{0.5}
\Row{0.75}
\Row{0.9}
\Row{1}
\Row{1.1}
\Row{1.25}
\Row{1.5}
\Row{2}
\end{array}
_{.}
$$

Each line is
$$
\boxed{
\begin{array}{l}
\color{blue}{\overbrace{\texttt{\displaystyle}}^{\text{with or without}}}
~\texttt{\{\sqrt\{6 + 2 \\sqrt\{7 + 3}
\\[0.5em]
\texttt{\\sqrt\{}
\color{red}{\texttt{\\vphantom\{\\rule\{0em\}}}
\color{red}{\underbrace{\texttt{\{}x~\texttt{em\}}}_{\begin{array}{c}\text{height} \\[-25px] \text{value}\end{array}} \texttt{\}}}
~\texttt{8 + \\cdots\}\}\}\}\}}
\end{array}
}_{,}
$$
with the coloring for the $\color{blue}{\texttt{\\displaystyle}}$ and ${\color{red}{\textbf{height}}}$ parts.

Comment: This is **_maybe_** the fifth most silly, pointless thing I've done with $\mathrm{\TeX}$ on StackExchange so far.

Comment: Just a little suggestion for the future: using [markdown table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables) would be better as every browser knows that its a table.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會: I'm glad that they finally added support for $\text{non-}\mathrm{\TeX}$ tables!  And I can see the potential advantage in using a simpler markup for a common presentation format like a table, perhaps making it easier for stuff like screen-readers.  That said, would there be a potential advantage in a case like this?  The content would seem fairly inaccessible to a screen-reader, with-or-without the table structure being a recognizable thing.

Comment: Note: I'm of the position that semantic AI-assistants will be a near-term technology, rendering programmer-compliance irrelevant in the foreseeable future.  So I'm generally skeptical of the idea that we should reach too far to make this stuff work, as an AI-assisted reader should view the content and redescribe to the reader as they prefer (including with respect to their preferred language and conceptual skillset), without need for content-providers to specify how this process should be done.  (Sorta like an improved [Word Lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_Lens).)

Comment: Thx for response.  I see your point.  Let machines do mechanical stuff.  In general, I observe a "syntactic simplicity–control over display" trade off.  In this case, using a Markdown table gives no advantage to human readers (using assistive technologies or not), and the syntax doesn't seem easier: each column is seperated by one character.  The syntactic complexity of the LaTeX code in each cell dominates that of the Markdown table.

Answer (score 1):

Info too long-winded for a comment:

> I dislike question titles which are all MathJax and no text. I tend to open questions by right-clicking on their titles, and this is not possible with all-MathJax titles.

**Firefox browser remedy**
(may work with other browsers)

1. Locate mouse just to the right of the query
2. right-click and
   choose inspect element from the pop-up menu
3. At this point, I have always had the inspection
   windows open up, with the (lower left pane) having the focus specifically on a compressed
   portion of the html code
4. Assuming you have the same experience, you can leave the mouse-focus
   as is, right-click the mouse, and then choose *expand all*
5. In the expanded area, one or two lines after the line that now has the mouse focus, you should see
   ...href="...".
6. Place the mouse focus inside the link, mouse-right-click, and then choose *Copy Link Address*.
7. Then close the *Developer Tool Panes*, manually go to a blank webpage, and then paste in
   the *copied* Link.

Comment: even though your answer addresses another question, your effort deserves an upvote