# What MathJax commands are most often used on this site?

Tags: support, mathjax, statistics

Following Mark Bennet's question on [Short and helpful advice on using Mathjax on this site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site), I've began drafting a tutorial aimed at complete beginners. It can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site/33183#33183). It is made up of $5$ sections:

1. Getting started
2. Understanding MathJax syntax
3. Numbers and arithmetic
4. Functions
5. Chaining syntax together

(There's also a section on calculus notation, but I'm considering breaking that off from the main answer since it doesn't strike me as completely essential that a user knows those commands right off the bat.)

I've tried my best to include the syntax that comes up the most frequently, but it's almost certain that I have omitted a thing or two. Does anyone have the technical know-how  to search through this site to find the MathJax commands that come up the most frequently in posts? Perhaps there is a way of finding this out using the site analytics. Thank you.

Comment: A simple way would to use the standard search with common commands. Like \frac, \sum, \int etc. This gives an idea of relative frequency. Since it's about frequent ones its not very likely that something relevant gets forgotten, especially if it is done as a group, posting results here. That said beyond absolute frequency there is also necessity. E.g., I frequently use \dots, but it's hardly essential and the the direct "..." is not that much worse.

Comment: `\dots`!?  Why not the slicker, more modern `\dotsc`, `\dotsb`, and so on?  :P

Comment: Heretics! Embrace the superior `\cdots`.

Comment: The trigonomtric functions $\sin x , \cos x \tan x$

Comment: I think the comments here suggest a short section on the fact that there are alternative ways of doing the same thing, and occasionally there are people who will insist that one is better than the other ... . Elegance can be possible, but comprehensibility is essential.

Comment: In reference to Arydeva's comment, we have `\sin x, \cos x, \tan x`, etc.

Comment: @Xander How'd you forget `\cdots`?  Also, separate from that, users should know that to write a set, using braces, then need to write `\{ fee, fie, fum\}`; without the backslash they will not render when surrounded with dollar signs, e.g. `${1, 2, \ldots}$` renders as ${1, 2, \ldots}$

Comment: Oops, I meant @AlexanderGruber:  just as important as `\cdots` are `\ldots`!!!

Comment: To @Joe, nothing in either your post suggests, and in Mark's post it is entirely overlooked the huge  field that logic plays in math: implies, if and only if, and, or, not, occur throughout most areas of mathematics:  In order: `\rightarrow or \to, \leftrightarrow or \iff, \land or \wedge, \lor or \vee, \lnot or \neg`

Comment: @amWhy I don't use `\cdots` or `\ldots`.  I use `\dotsc` for dots in lists (this is essentially `\ldots`, but with slightly more semantic information, `\dotsb` between binary operators (like `\cdots`, but with better spacing), and `\dotsi` between integrals (like `\cdots`, but with better spacing for integrals.  There are several similar commands:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122491/difference-of-the-dots .

Comment: I suggest that in different fields of math, the most basic commands needed to initially post questions are far more than calculus-oriented commands. Perhaps we need  to identify the primary commands needed Freshman/Sophomore/Junior level classes.

Comment: @Xander Heretic!   No seriously, that's good to know!

Comment: Joe, has anything been mentioned about  writing fractions?   Instead of seeing countless examples of "how to reduce 1+x/(1-x)^2 which is entirely ambiguous, highlighting `\frac {1+x}{(1-x^2}` would save askers and potential answerers a whole lot of time and spare them from frustration.  Similar, `\gcd(foo, fie)`  `\mid`.  If you want basic think basic.

Comment: `\mod`, `\bmod` and `\pmod` might be worth a mention.

Comment: `\Bbb` for our favourite sets, `\tag` for equation numbering, `align` environment for long chains of equations, ...

Comment: @amWhy: Thank you for all of your suggestions. I have mentioned fractions in the [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site/33183#33183) in the section titled **3. Numbers and arithmetic**. Regarding the ambiguity about the way fractions are sometimes written, this is alluded to in the section titled **5. Chaining syntax together** (though not directly addressed). Please let me know if you find this insufficient.

Comment: @amWhy: Regarding logic, the reason I have not mentioned it in the beginners tutorial is because I have no problem with a new contributor using everyday language rather than Mathjax. Something like "why does $y=\sqrt{x^2}$ imply that $y=|x|$" rather than "why does $y=\sqrt{x^2} \implies y = |x|$" seems fine to me. Of course, there may well be instances where everyday language is difficult to parse. Hence, I think logic does have a place in the 'Short and helpful advice' thread, just not the beginners tutorial. It's for the same reason that I have split off the calculus section from the...

Comment: ...main tutorial, as I think asking "what is the limit of $\sin x / x$ as $x$ approaches $0$" is also fine. Again, there may be instances where it is impossible to explain your question in everyday language. Hence, I think this should be in the tutorial, just not in my answer that is aimed at complete beginners. The beginners tutorial is already at $1200$ words, and I'm worried that if it gets much bigger, it might just ward off new contributors rather than help them.

Comment: @amWhy: Finally, I appreciate the need for people who are different stages of education will need different commands. So far, I have split up the tutorial into categories such as 'numbers and arithmetic', 'functions', 'calculus'. If you think there is a better way of organising the categories, then please let me know.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Thank you for your suggestions. I'm definitely going to include `\Bbb`/`\mathbb`, especially since Glorfindel's search revealed they are some of the most used commands on this site. I'm reluctant to mention aligning equations in the beginner's tutorial, because the aim is to help new users achieve basic competency, and so aesthetic considerations are of secondary importance. However, someone will mentioned them in some of the answers to Mark Bennet's question.

Comment: @PeterPhipps: Thank you for your suggestions. Having looked through Glorfindel's search, I don't think the mod commands arise enough to have them in the beginner's tutorial (my answer), but perhaps they can be included in a separate answer to Mark Bennet's question.

Comment: @amWhy: In the newly added miscallaneous commands section, I have now mentioned `\implies` and `\iff`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible to analyze this with help of the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) if you know a bit of SQL. The procedure is as follows:

- Split the body of the post into several chunks, splitting on the `\` character
- Check which alphabetical characters appear at the beginning of each chunk

  - Luckily, all posts starts with `<p>` so the first chunk, which is not a MathJax command, is ignored

Aggregate all the results, and you get [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1376763/frequency-of-mathjax-commands-in-posts). I'm actually surprised it didn't timeout on the volume of posts, but here are the commands which are used over a million times:

| Command | Times used |
| --- | --- |
| `\frac` | 5248808 |
| `\mathbb` | 1861001 |
| `\in` | 1668461 |
| `\right` | 1552969 |
| `\left` | 1539656 |
| `\sqrt` | 1248791 |
| `\infty` | 1205941 |
| `\pi` | 1059025 |
| `\int` | 1042355 |
| `\sum` | 1036783 |

Of course, this does not cover the other syntaxes (e.g. curly braces), but at least it's a start.

Comment: This is precisely what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: How does one have `\right` without a matching `\left`?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire no idea, but it doesn't feel `\right` ...

Comment: I don't know SQL but perhaps can search for all posts `CONTAINING \right NOT \left` -- I suspect most of them will actually be examples of incorrect MathJax where the equations aren't displayed correctly.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Some of those occurrences might be *outside* MathJax. (AFAICT it would be rather difficult to include also a test whether the text is inside MathJax, because there are many various ways how one could enter MathJax.)

Comment: If somebody wants play around a bit more, here are [Posts with macro1 but not macro2](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1377025/posts-with-macro1-but-not-macro2?macro1=right&macro2=left). There are at least some posts [which contain the string "left\right"](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1377026/posts-containing-the-given-word?word=left\right) in the text (outside MathJax). My guess would be that various similar cases might be responsible for the difference. (You might notice that there's also a different number of occurrences of \begin and \end - maybe for similar reasons.)