# how to ask good question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm new to this community& mathematics is my weakness. I found some answers in this community that were very helpful and decided to join and ask questions. But some of my questions were not received well and now I'm not allowed to ask questions for 3 days. I don't know the code or shortcuts for math symbols like sigma, pi, exponentials etc. My intention is never to sound rude or be impolite while asking the question. Can you please help me by giving suggestions on how to write a good question and how to incorporate the math symbols while asking? ( sorry if I sounded rude or blunt)

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Since you asked about math symbols: [Short and helpful advice on using MathJax on the site …](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179) and [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: You might want to read math.SE _tour_: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Yuna The entry barrier to stackexchange is very high, first of all you need to know what to ask (i.e: math) , then you need to be able to know how to formulate that question into words, thirdly you must know how to use latex. I can understand where you are coming from as I felt the same when I began using this site, but it gets better with time. For now, I suggest learnign mathjax and reading the guides which otehrs have linked! Hope to see you as an active member!

Comment: To add to the above comment, I checked your questions, I think the main problem is that you aren't showing your attempts in the questions. The culture here is that people appreciate if you show the work/ attempts you ahve made. If you are completely clueless on the question , I suggest googlign and seeing some youtube videos before posting the question.