# Need some help not in a math problem but in something else.....

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Hope this problem might get resolved before someone closes this.

---

The problem is that I don't know how to type using Mathjax so what should I do in this situation?

---

The things which I think I can do in this situation is:-

---

-(1)- Have faith in luck - by this, I mean that, post my question without using Mathjax and hoping that before it gets closed, someone answers it.

---

-(2)- learn Mathjax:-I know if anyone answers this question, most probably(orthodox) they will choose this one, I don't know from where to start, and How much time will it take? so if anyone picks this he/she must care that they should also answer this.

---

-(3)- any other alternative if you have in place of the above two if anyone has.
Thank you.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and further links. It's really just a dumbed down verison of Latex, so you might want to invest time into learning actual Latex, because it's more likely to be useful for your real-life career. Knowing latex already helps with mathjax.

Comment: Basic MathJax is easy: `$x^2-1=3$` gives $x^2-1=3$.  Then build up from there: for example using `$\frac{\sigma^2_X}{\mu}$` gives $\frac{\sigma^2_X}{\mu}$  and so on

Comment: Why is there a fear that this is getting closed? Ah, I see that it emerged from the math site, but it was truly meant to be on meta, and here it is, it's not going anywhere now.

Comment: [FYI](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: ok, I will try tomorrow.

Comment: [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site/33183#33183) article is the BEST place to go to learn MathJax. Leave your feedback in the comments once you've read the post, also provide feedback to the answer below, your feedback is important for any answerer to adapt their answer and respond to you as deemed fit. Thank you.

Answer (score -4):

yes, what, "you have asked, for this I can only say that there is a proverb in Hindi (aapne mere muh ki baat rakh di), I also have a problem in this due to this only I never answered any question. The last time I have asked a question nearly 5 people replied that use Mathlax and edit it, write it properly, then only he can answer and give (-1) point and closes it. I waited 40 minutes posted again with some edit but this also not enough to satisfy them. once again same thing. but then there came a person I think (Teresa) she is a nice lady, she understood my problem and edited it and reopens it and also solved the problem too. so option 1 is risky because there is very less person like (Teresa). so option 2 is best. if you have time then carefully observe the patterns as they can be written in a fixed way as Henry has written above.

Comment: Option 2 is very much the best, thank you for the kind words, आप के मुँह में घी शक्कर. To me you can speak in Hindi, but MathJax is the second language of this site after English, so that has to be learnt by anybody and everybody visiting the site. It is very easy. There's literally just the dollar signs `$`, the power sign `^`, the fraction construct `\frac`, the underscore `_` and a lot of things like brackets, math operations etc. match perfectly with written mathematics. It is easy, and anyone can learn the basics in one day, or by trying to write one answer.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Sorry, first I thought that you are a boy but now I saw your profile and I have corrected it also. and How do you know Hindi, as you do not look Indian by your name?

Comment: Oh, the username is not an indicator of where I am from. But one small thing I am going to request you to do : there are many like me on the site, who will be helpful. I request you to remove the personal references to me. I will be helpful to you, but I think that it could sway the answer if it turns out to only be in praise of me, when there are so many doing the same work as me but far better than me. You can say : "there are helpful people on the site", that's good enough. Thanks!

Comment: And [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site/33183#33183) article is the BEST place to go to learn MathJax. Leave your feedback in the comments once you've read the post.

Comment: so the feedback is that it is helpful. I have answered a question, I hope I did it correctly (typing).